# Chart's width is impacting to my second x axis labels in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

In the application I'm working on I have a chart with **two x axes**. Both are of `category` type (but I think that's irrelevant) and all the series have to be attached to the first axis, so the second has no related data.

The problem is that depending on the width of the chart, the second **axis labels** are rendered or not. **I want always to render them** (because it is completely related to the first one). I have tried many things:

- To apply `linkedTo` axis property on second axis. Not valid becuase the representation of the axis is wrong.
- To assign a series to the second axis. Not valid because the representation of the data is not real and even if it comes with no data, we have the same problem with the axis.
- I've been playing with chart margins with no success.

I have created an example in [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/jsh9wv8o/). There you can see how the second axis just renders its horizontal line. If you modify the css class `highcharts-figure`, by narrowing the element, for instance, setting a width of `800px` and render again the chart, you can see the labels for both axes. That's my goal. But I want it for any size of the chart.

This example runs with Highcharts in `v6.1.0` because is the version installed in my app, but this issue happens with the latest version as well.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

This must be a bug? I found that removing width altogether from CSS allows it to render properly at all widths, but unfortunately the initial render is still wrong.

Comment: I've just tried it and you are right! If nobody finds a good explanation of this behavior, I should let highcharts devs know this problem. Because for my particular situation, is a litlle complicated to get rid of the width containers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug to me also. Could you report it on [Highcharts Github issue channel](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues)?

As a temporary workaround, you can do an update on this additonal xAxis and "force" chart to show this axis again. See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lrwcyh0v/).

```
  chart: {
    events: {
        load(){
        this.xAxis[1].update({
            visible: true
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

**API**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Comment: Done. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12486
I've tried your proposal and I'll try to implement it soon in my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The bug is [published in the `highcharts github`](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r7gupcnL/) and there is another workaround for this issue.

Basically, it consists on assign to the second axis a fake series, as simple as:

```
{
    showInLegend: false,
    xAxis: 1
  }
```

Here you have the full example: [workaround](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r7gupcnL/).

(In my original post I said that I tried a similar solution -to add empty series to the second axis- and that it didn't worked for me. The most likely is that I was wrong, becuase I've tried this workaround and it's working fine.)